# Template constructor: is this a case of the most vexing parse?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, clang++, most-vexing-parse

I have the following snippet (I'm compiling for C++20):

```
struct Z {
    template <typename... Args>
    Z(std::vector<std::tuple<Args...>>) {}
};

Z z(std::vector{std::tuple{}});
```

`g++-10` refuses to compile this with the error:

```
main.cpp:16:9: error: ‘auto’ parameter not permitted in this context
   16 |     Z z(std::vector{std::tuple{}});
      |         ^~~
```

However, `clang++` version 10 successfully compiles it (and does the right thing if I create non-empty tuples and try printing their contents).

Is this a case of the most vexing parse? If so, how does `clang++` manage to compile this? Otherwise, is this a bug with `g++`?

Answer (score 3):

This is not the most vexing parse. The use of braces prevents the most vexing parse: for example, `std::tuple{}` cannot be interpreted as "function taking no arguments and returning `std::tuple`", while `std::tuple()` can. This means the latter can be part of a most vexing parse, while the former cannot.

This simply appears to be a bug in GCC, which is fixed in the "trunk" version currently on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Kds7hcr5f